# "Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first" Error on second call of window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently trying to fix a bug where i load my window1 after logging into my application (which works fine), then i use functionality i created to go back to the login form to change the logged on user and i get an error when loading my Window1 for the second time

Error message
"Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first."

window1 code is

```
public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var tc = TabsControl.Instance as Control;
            Grid.SetColumn(tc, 1);
            Grid.SetRow(tc, 1);

            //error happens on this line
            grdMainContent.Children.Add(tc);
}
```

not sure how to disconnect this element, and have sofar been unsuccessful on google.

what i have tried are the following things.

```
grdMainContent.Children.Remove(tc);
```

and

```
if (!grdMainContent.Children.Contains(TabsControl.Instance as Control))
            {
                 grdMainContent.Children.Add(tc);
            }
```

and

```
if (grdMainContent.Children.Contains(tc))
            {
                grdMainContent.Children.Add(tc);
            }
```

Any help is as always greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you seem to reuse TabsControl that was previously used and added as a Children of grdMainContent in another instance of your window.

You can detach it with:

```
Grid parentGrid = tc.Parent as Grid;
If(parentGrid != null) {
    parentGrid.Children.Remove(tc);
}
```